# Strange file upload failure

Tags: php, apache, symfony, laravel

It's Laravel at AWS. Upload is working fine at local as well as AWS few months ago. They are the same code deployed. I captured `Input::all()`:

**Working at Local**: (apache at Mac)

```
Array
(
[_token] => abc…… 
[text] => 
[file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
    (
        [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 
        [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => file.txt
        [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => text/plain
        [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 18
        [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] => /private/var/tmp/phpetUgq0
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] => phpetUgq0
    )
)
```

**Fail at AWS**:

```
Array
(
[_token] => xyc…… 
[text] =>
[file] => Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile Object
    (
        [test:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] =>
        [originalName:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => file.txt
        [mimeType:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => application/octet-stream
        [size:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 0
        [error:Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile:private] => 6
        [pathName:SplFileInfo:private] =>
        [fileName:SplFileInfo:private] =>
    )
)
```

No common mistake e.g. it must be `enctype="multipart/form-data"` etc, and I have restarted `httpd` and `mysqld`.

I'm afraid it might be something fundamental but I have no idea yet what direction I should look at. Could you please advise any possibilities? Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there is no issue with permissions in this?

Comment: Thank you for comment. I finally found it's because of open_basedir setting in apache configuration. I set it several weeks ago due to security concern but missed the temp directory, no problem occurred until uploading files.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could be of help :)